# How to print multiple artboards on one page each with individual trim marks in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I've tried putting everything in one large artboard and printing that large artboard, but it would not show the trim marks for the smaller artboards.

Answer (score 2):

**To place trim marks around artboards**

Select **File → Save As** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and select PDF

Once the PDF options come up, click on **Marks and Bleeds** and check **Trim Marks**

---

**To place crop marks around individual objects**

Select all items you want and go to **Effect → Crop Marks** this will apply crop marks (trim marks) to each object.

See [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/92154/63979) for more.

Comment: Is the PDF going to retain CMYK profile?

Comment: @KamilaMielczarek yes thats the purpose of PDF